# Creating list with count of values depending on time interval in another column that has a timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, a string and a datetime, like the following:

```
ORDER        TIMESTAMP
GO     6/4/2019 09:59:49.497000
STAY   6/4/2019 09:05:27.036000
WAIT   6/4/2019 10:33:05.645000
GO     6/4/2019 10:28:03.649000
STAY   6/4/2019 11:23:11.614000
GO     6/4/2019 11:00:33.574000
WAIT   6/4/2019 11:41:55.744000
```

I want to create a list where each entry is a list with three values.
For each time interval of choice (say one hour), each entry is: [beginning time, total number of rows, percent of rows with order GO].

For example, for the dataframe above, my list would be:

```
[6/4/2019 09:00:00.000000, 2, 50]
[6/4/2019 10:00:00.000000, 2, 50]
[6/4/2019 11:00:00.000000, 3, 33.3]
```

I created a simple while loop:

```
go= []
while t<=df["timestamp"].iloc[-1]:
  tmp1 = df[(df["date_time"]>=t) & (df["timestamp"]<t+timedelta(hour=1))]
  tmp2 = df[(df["date_time"]>=t) & (df["timestamp"]<t+timedelta(hour=1)) & (df["Order"]=="GO")]
  go.append([t, tmp1.shape[0], 100.0*tmp2.shape[0]/tmp1.shape[0]])
  #increment the time by the interval
  t=t+timedelta(hour=1)
```

However, my initial dataframe has millions of rows, and I would like my time interval to be much shorter than an hour, so this approach is VERY slow.
What is the more pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `groupby().agg()` with `size` for number of rows and `mean` to get the ratio of rows with `GO`:

```
(df.ORDER.eq('GO').astype(int)
   .groupby(df.TIMESTAMP.dt.floor('1H'))   # groupby interval of choice
   .agg(['size','mean'])
   .reset_index()              # get timestamp back
   .to_numpy().tolist()        # this is to generate the list
)
```

Output:

```
[[Timestamp('2019-06-04 09:00:00'), 2, 0.5],
 [Timestamp('2019-06-04 10:00:00'), 2, 0.5],
 [Timestamp('2019-06-04 11:00:00'), 3, 0.3333333333333333]]
```